Kotlin channel vs vert.x event bus
We are using kotlin to write vert.x based backend service.
The requirement is to do async processing upon http request, after receiving a request, create a job in db and return the job_id immediately, then start background processing.
Later, the client can query the job status or result using job_id.
We are not deploying vert.x in cluster (using cluster manager or something like that in near future), may I know is there any pros and cons between using vert.x event bus and Kotlin coroutine channel in such case?
Thanks!
There is some internal discussion, people are saying if using Kotlin then need to stick to coroutine channel.

I'm not sure if I understand your case correctly, but using coroutines makes the most sense if we use it for most of our application. If you mean to use Channel for a single feature and don't use coroutines in general, then I think you won't benefit from it and it may be a little annoying to use. Also, how do you want to use the event bus / channel? According to what you said, nobody waits for the async task, so who do you want to notify about the status?

I think in this case, both coroutine channel and vert.x event bus works. In coroutine channel, I need to create separate channel for each async job type for different job request payload. In vert.x event bus, I create each coroutine verticles for each different async job type and use event bus to send message and dispatch the job request to various verticles.
But inside the vert.x coroutine verticle, normally I still need to create other coroutines like querying dbs, do parallel processing, etc.

If you‘re not on a cluster, using the EventBus may seem like an unnecessary overhead. But it’s not.
It is the facility (for Vert.x) that enables location transparency, which means it won’t matter if you scale your app on the same machine by throwing more CPUs in, or if you add more nodes to a cluster.
Take an example: A Verticle which acts as EventBus consumer, if overrun by incoming messages, can be scaled up by deploying more instances (of that Verticle). It does not matter where they are deployed. And you won’t need to change a line of code for this. The EventBus will take care of routing the events to the right place.
Coroutines and Channels are nice, but they aren’t quite comparable to what the EventBus allows you to do.
